# How to reset angular grid list and load new filtered items?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here my Angular template grid list code

```
  <mat-grid-list cols=3 gutterSize="5px" style="text-align: center;">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of items" >
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-list >
            <mat-list-item  >
                <p matLine>
                  <img mat-card-image src="{{item.photo}}" alt="Shoping Item" style="height: 80px; width: 100px;">
                </p>
                <p matLine>
                  <mat-card-title class="item_title">{{item.title}}</mat-card-title>
                </p>
                <p matLine>
                    <span class="price">Rs. <span >{{item.price}}</span></span> 
                </p>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```

I send data by below TS code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    var url ="http://54.25.52.315:3000/api/items";
    this.http.get(url,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
      (data :any) =>{
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);  

          for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
           var img="http://54.25.52.315:3000/"+obj[i].photo;

        this.items.push({id: obj[i].id, 
                         title: obj[i].title, 
                         price : obj[i].price,
                         categoty:obj[i].category,
                         photo: img});
          }

        }
    );
  }
```

In this code, I successfully pass the data to the grid list.
Can reset and load new filtered data set to the same grid list by clicking the button

ex:-

```
<button (click)="fashionCategoty()">
```

Using this button how to filter and load only category= "fashion" items to the same grid list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could apply a filter. I'll provide a way where you don't recall the `http.get`

In your TS file, create a new field to store the items that should be shown. Default it to all items:

```
this.http.get(url,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
  (data :any) => {
    const obj = JSON.parse(data);  
    for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
      this.items.push({...obj[i], photo: `http://54.25.52.315:3000/${obj[i].photo}` });
    }
    this.itemsToShow = this.items;
  }
);
```

In you template, loop through the `itemsToShow` instead

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of itemsToShow" >
```

For the `fashionCategoty()` function, set the `itemsToShow` to a filtered version of `items`

```
fashionCategoty() {
  this.itemsToShow = this.items.filter(item => item.category === 'fashion');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your category is 'fashion' filter the list using the filter method. To filter the data in the list you can use the following code

```js
fashionCategoty(){
this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.category === 'fashion')
}
```

If you want to reset the filter you can have another list called allItems to hold all the initial items

For Example you can modify your ngOnInit function as below

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    var url ="http://54.25.52.315:3000/api/items";
    this.http.get(url,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
      (data :any) =>{
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);  

          for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
           var img="http://54.25.52.315:3000/"+obj[i].photo;

        this.items.push({id: obj[i].id, 
                         title: obj[i].title, 
                         price : obj[i].price,
                         categoty:obj[i].category,
                         photo: img});

 this.allItems.push({id: obj[i].id, 
                         title: obj[i].title, 
                         price : obj[i].price,
                         categoty:obj[i].category,
                         photo: img});
          }

        }
    );
  }
```

In this case your filter method would be

```js
fashionCategoty(){
this.items = this.allItems.filter(item => item.category === 'fashion')
}
```

This way you don't lose the data that was loaded initially and can also filter and reset as required.

Comment: Good answer, looks like we had the same idea :)